# Not able to get Logger from `IServiceProvider` in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.Net on a Net 6 Worker project with Serilog for Logging.

I am using a custom `JobFactory`:

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory {

  private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;  
  
  public JobFactory(IServiceProvider provider) {  
    _provider = provider;  
  }
  
  public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler) { 

    Logger logger = _provider.GetRequiredService<Logger>();

    IDataService service = _provider.GetRequiredService<IDataService>();

    Manager manager = new Manager(logger, service);
    
    return new ManagerJob(manager, logger);
  
  } 

}
```

In `NewJob` method `service` is defined but `logger` is undefined. No idea why.

I am using Serilog and the configuration is Program.cs is:

```
Serilog.Log.Logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateBootstrapLogger();

try {

  Serilog.Log.Information("Starting up");

  IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
  
  builder.UseSerilog((context, configuration) = configuration.WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
  });

  builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {

    services.AddQuartz(x => {

      x.SchedulerId = "Bot";
      x.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

      x.UseJobFactory<JobFactory>();
        
      x.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
      x.UseInMemoryStore();
        
      x.UseDefaultThreadPool(y => {
        y.MaxConcurrency = 20;
      });

      foreach (Manager manager in getManagers()) {

        x.ScheduleJob<TraderJob>(
          y => y.WithIdentity(manager.Name).WithCronSchedule(manager.Cron),
          y => y.WithIdentity(manager.Name).UsingJobData(new JobDataMap((IDictionary<String, Object>) new Dictionary<String, Object> { { "Strategy", manager.Strategy } }))
        );

      }

    });

    services.AddQuartzHostedService(x => {
      x.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
    });

    services.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>();      

  });

  using IHost host = builder.Build();

  await host.RunAsync();

} 

catch (Exception exception) {
  Serilog.Log.Fatal(exception, "Unhandled exception");
}

finally {
  Serilog.Log.Information("Shutdown complete");
  Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That's because, by default, there is no `Logger.` registered in DI, also no `ILogger.` But there is an `ILogger<T>` when `T` can be anything (open generic). So try to resolve `ILogger<Manager>` and `ILogger<ManagerJob>` instead.

Comment: This is confusing.  I am able to. inject `Serilog.Core.Logger` in a class constructor. But, as you said, when using provide, I need to use `ILogger<Manager> logger = _provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Manager>>();` where ILogger is Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.

Comment: Can't I get an instance of `Serilog.Core.Logger` with the provider? And should I use `Serilog.Core.Logger` or `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but `JobFactory(IServiceProvider provider)` is an anti-pattern called service locator. You don't need to and should not inject an IServiceProvider, just inject the services that you do need

Comment: You are able to inject `Logger`? That's interesting. I have no experience with Serilog, but if you are able to inject it, you should be able to retrieve it from the provider.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, I just changed it and started to inject everything on the constructor and now I am able to inject `Serilog.ILogger`

Comment: @Artur Yes, Serilog.ILogger I can ... I don't need to inject Logger<SomeClass>

Comment: Great :) I'd suggest you to inject only `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>` though, Serilog will still get the logs and you can get rid of Serilog if you don't need it later on

Comment: "I'm able to inject Logger" and "I'm able to inject ILogger" are not the same things. Don't mix classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get Logger

```
Logger logger = _provider.GetRequiredService<Logger>();
```

maybe you should `services.Addsingleton<Logger>(Serilog.Log.Logger)` in your Program.cs